# Moving markers between source to destination position through poly line with correct turning on route

Tags: android

I have current location marker and near by places marker.i have to move my current position marker to the destination position.

But my current position marker was moving out of poly line.it's not moving on the poly line path.can anyone suggest correct solution to me.Please, Thanks in Advance

My code for moving marker on map

public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition, final boolean hideMarker)

```
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = googleMap.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());

    final long duration =1000;
    final LinearInterpolator interpolator = new  LinearInterpolator();
    handler.post(new Runnable()
    {


        public void run()
```

{

```
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);




            double lng = t * latlng_value.longitude + (1 - t)
                    * latlng.longitude;
            double lat = t * latlng_value.latitude + (1 - t)
                    * latlng.latitude;






            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));





            if (t < 1.0) 
            {



                  // Post again 16ms later.
                  handler.postDelayed(this, 10);  
            } 
            else 
            {


                if (hideMarker) 
                {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the code for this: http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part3
it's a very good example, basically you have to concatenate a set of animation for each "subline" of the polyline.

To get a subpath of the line you can use the library "google-maps-utils" that has an interpolate function

Comment: I gone throw this link but my marker is not moving through polyline path .